# Laravel Mail::queue error: Serialization of closure failed, even with the most basic usage

Tags: php, laravel, closures, laravel-5

I'm having issues with `Mail::queue()` and not sure what can even be done to solve it outside of writing my own `Job` to handle the queueing. As you can see in the screenshot below, I have an extremely minimal example that I'm trying to run in `artisan tinker`. Has anyone had, and solved, this issue?

This works perfectly fine if I use `Mail::send()` instead;

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Do you use SuperClosure?

Comment: You can see in the PHP error there that SuperClosure is being used, but that's kind of not the point. The point is that the above code doesn't work in Tinker, nor in the actual application. I'm trying to discern whether or not it's some configuration option on my end or if this is a problem other people are experiencing in a default installation of Laravel 5.2.

Comment: It's required by Laravel, in the laravel/framework/composer.json.

Comment: Can you post your activate.blade.php file?

Comment: Activate.blade.php's content is "test".

Comment: Inside the closure there is no code? Try to add a $message->to('your@email'); Also which driver are you using?

Comment: Did you setup your queue table? See https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#introduction

Comment: I don't have queues running through the database, but I have tried it with the database driver as well with no go.

Comment: Which driver are you using then?
Also make sure to fill the closure like @LuisDalmolin already stated...

Answer (score 0):

Closures are not serializable. You can not push them to the queue.

```
Psy Shell v0.8.3 (PHP 7.1.0 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> serialize(function(){});
Exception with message 'Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed'
```

Comment: This is an older post and your answer isn't applicable. In Laravel 5.2, the above code is still on the 5.2 documentation, but it doesn't work. `Mail::queue('emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) {
    //
});` is taken from the documentation page.

Either way, this is mostly closed now because it's several versions old and the entire queue system has changed.